# Display column values in rows according to index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a DataFrame with this structure

```
            Date              Values
Variable                
Var1        01/01/2021 0:00     1
Var1        01/01/2021 1:00     2
Var1        01/01/2021 2:00     3
Var2        01/01/2021 0:00     4
Var2        01/01/2021 1:00     5
Var3        01/01/2021 0:00     6
Var3        01/01/2021 1:00     7
Var3        01/01/2021 2:00     8
Var3        01/01/2021 3:00     9
```

and I want to flip both columns `Date` and `Values` to build a single row per `Variable`:

```
        01/01/2021 0:00     01/01/2021 1:00     01/01/2021 2:00     01/01/2021 3:00
Var1           1                   2                   3                  NaN
Var2           4                   5                  NaN                 NaN
Var3           6                   7                   8                   9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Date', append=True)['Values'].unstack()
print (df1)
Date      01/01/2021 0:00  01/01/2021 1:00  01/01/2021 2:00  01/01/2021 3:00
Variable                                                                    
Var1                  1.0              2.0              3.0              NaN
Var2                  4.0              5.0              NaN              NaN
Var3                  6.0              7.0              8.0              9.0
```

And last add [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index('Date', append=True)['Values']
         .unstack()
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (df1)
      01/01/2021 0:00  01/01/2021 1:00  01/01/2021 2:00  01/01/2021 3:00
Var1              1.0              2.0              3.0              NaN
Var2              4.0              5.0              NaN              NaN
Var3              6.0              7.0              8.0              9.0
```

Comment: how can I convert the value 1.0 to 1, in this case? maybe that would be better if the type is int.

Comment: @everfight - There are `NaN`s, so possible solution is [`.astype('Int64')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html)